# ¿Como puedo incrementar el índice de una <List> y volver a la primera posición cuando llegue al final? c#

Tags: c#, wpf

> Lo que busco es obtener las posición (índice), y recorrer la lista de forma ciclica por medio de un boton, y cuando se llegue al final del índice, volver a la primera posición (ósea [0] en el ArrayList).

> Adjunto codigo para mejor entendimiento, esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora.

```
public Producto nextProduct()
        {
            Producto p;
            int i = lista.Count - 1;

            if (lista.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Aún no hay ningún producto", "AVISO", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                return null;
            }
            else if (lista.Count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sólo existe este producto", "AVISO", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                p = lista.First();
                return p;
            }
            else if (lista.Count > 1)
            {                                
                //Codigo a desarrollar...
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }            
        }
```

Comment: Hola has intentado con una variable que indique la ubicación? Por ejemplo int pos =1, return p[pos] ... Si pos = I then pps = 1...

Comment: 1. Agrega esta variable de alcance público: private static int posicion = -1;

Comment: 1. //Codigo a desarrollar... 
-> if( posicion == -1 || ( posicion =>lista.Count-1) ) posicion = 0;
p = lista[posicion++];

Comment: A ver suponiendo q la lista tenga mas de un elemento tu lo q quires es q cuando se apriete el boton muestre el elemento actual, se vuelva a apretar el siguiente y asi sucesivamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como sabrás SO no es para hacer tareas, sin embargo este ejemplo ayuda claramente a resolver el problema sin caer en el error clásico de hacer las tareas.

```
private int posicion = -1; // Vacío

public Producto First() // Esto establece el valor vacío.
{
    posicion = 0;
}

public Producto nextProduct()
    {
        Producto p;

        if (lista.Count == 0)
        {
            posicion = -1;
            MessageBox.Show("Aún no hay ningún producto", "AVISO", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            if( posicion == -1 || ( posicion =>lista.Count-1) )
            {
                // Sí la posicion es -1 o es mayor que el valor de las listas Reiniciar
                First();
            }
            
            p = lista[posicion++]; // Se asigna el valor ( la pregunta inicial evita un desbordamiento)

            //posicion++ para aumentar de una vez y apuntar a la siguient posicion.
            return p;
        }
                     
    }
```

Comment: Hola @Favio Palm, gracias por usar tu tiempo para compartir tu solución alternativa, lo he probado y funciona. Por otro lado aunque tengas razón con lo de las "tareas" en cierto modo, uso el sitio para aprender por supuesto.
Saludos !